Identify an Actress in Impluse Body Spray commercial from early 2000s
Hi I'm trying to identify an actress that I saw in a commercial in the early 2000s.
The advert was shown on UK TV and was promoting Impulse body spray. 
In the story a woman (the actress) heads in to a coffee shop and ends up crossing paths with a guy her age and a guy a lot older. I think it turns out that in the end they are father and son.
The older man is played by the actor Robert Forster!
I seem to vaguely recall the actress's name was something like Jennifer Hutton? - maybe.

I'm pretty sure it's not Robert Forster (according to online sources, it's Ben Murphy), but you were close regarding the actress. Her name is Jennifer Renton according to this article: 

In the ad Jennifer encounters two men. First she bumps into the boy next door as she dashes off to work. Then she serves coffee to an older man in a bar before the two males meet and she realises she has been flirting with a father and son. 

And here's her picture from the series 'Mortal Kombat: Conquest'.
